# Click event outside MovieClip in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

**Is there any way to detect if the user click outside a MovieClip?**

For instance, I need to detect it to close a previously opened menu (like Menu bar style: File, Edition, Tools, Help, etc).

[image]

How can I detect this kind of event? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a listener to stage and check if `stage` is the target of the event.

Example of code here:
http://wonderfl.net/c/eFao

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class FlashTest extends Sprite
    {

        private var _menu : Sprite;

        public function FlashTest()
        {
            _menu = new Sprite();
            _menu.x = 100;
            _menu.y = 100;
            _menu.alpha = 0.5;

            with(_menu.graphics)
            {
                beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
                drawRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
                endFill();
            }

            addChild(_menu);

            _menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);

        }

        private function onClickHandler(event : MouseEvent) : void
        {
            switch(event.target)
            {
                case _menu:
                    _menu.alpha = 0.5;
                    break;

                case stage:
                    _menu.alpha = 1;
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a listener to the click event of the root element:

```
MovieClip(root).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickObject);
```

then in the function clickObject, you can check to see what you are clicking.

```
function clickObject(e:Event):void
{
    var hoverArray:Array = MovieClip(root).getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY));
    var hoverOverObject:* = hoverArray[hoverArray.length - 1];
}
```

hoverOverObject references the element that you are clicking on. Often this will be the shape within the movie clip, so you'll need to look at it's parent then compare it to your movie clip. If the click wasn't on the drop down movie clip, trigger the close.

Comment: this works but i don't understand why hoverOverObject != e.target

Answer (score 1):

```
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
with(mc.graphics){
    beginFill(0xff0000,1);
    drawCircle(0,0,30);
    endFill();
}
mc.name = "my_mc";
container.addChild(mc);
addChild(container);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, action);
function action (e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(e.target.name != "my_mc"){
        if(container.numChildren != 0)
        {
            container.removeChild(container.getChildByName("my_mc"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use capture phase:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button_mouseClickHandler);
button.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stage_mouseClickHandler, true);
//...

private function button_mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Button CLICK");
}
private function stage_mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (event.target == button)
        return;
    trace("Button CLICK_OUTSIDE");
}
```

Note that using stopPropagation() is good for one object, but failed for several. This approach works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stage and a sprite (menu) click listener with the sprite listener executing first and apply the stopPropagation() method to the click handler of the sprite.  Like this:

```
menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMenuClick);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleStageClick);

private function handleMenuClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    // stop the event from propagating up to the stage
    // so handleStageClick is never executed.
    e.stopPropagation();
    // note that stopPropagation() still allows the event
    // to propagate to all children so if there are children
    // within the menu overlay that need to respond to click
    // events that still works.  
}

private function handleStageClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    // put hide or destroy code here
}
```

The idea is that a mouse click anywhere creates a single MouseEvent.CLICK event that bubbles from the stage, down through all children to the target, then back up through the parents of the target to the stage.  Here we interrupt this cycle when the target is the menu overlay by not allowing the event to propagate back up to the parent stage, ensuring that the handleStageClick() method is never invoked.  The nice thing about this approach is that it is completely general.  The stage can have many children underneath the overlay and the overlay can have its own children that can respond to clicks and it all works.